# ¿En un archivo JAVA por qué solamente una clase puede ser pública?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber ¿por qué en un archivo Java únicamente puede haber una clase con el modificador de acceso public?, además, ¿el método main debe estar obligatoriamente en esa clase pública o puede estar en otra diferente?

Comment: Es uno de los standares de `java` por cada archivo `.java` únicamente puedes tener solo una clase pública. Pero si puedes tener mas de una clase en el mismo archivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, es posible que tener multiples clases publicas, y eligar ejecutar cual clase en el *command line*: [How to run a class from Jar which is not the Main-Class in its Manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474748/4751173):

```
java -cp MiJar.jar com.example.ClaseUn
java -cp MiJar.jar com.example.ClaseDos
java -cp MiJar.jar com.example.ClaseTres
```

El metodo `main` debe ser en una clase publica.

Comment: falta aclarar porque solamente una clase puede ser publica por archivo...

Comment: Tengo muchas clases publicas en un solo archivo para ejecutar unas aplicaciones de Stack Exchange. No estoy haciendo nada especial: `java -cp SE-toolbox.jar com.stackexchange.toolbox.editor.bir.BrokenImageRepairer`, `java -cp SE-toolbox.jar com.stackexchange.toolbox.notifier.Notifier` ...

Comment: ahhh entonces el problema es que solo una se puede ejecutar ;) capaz hay que explicar bien eso ;)